# Problems specifying path of TeXLive 2020 on Fedora 33

Tags: fedora, software-installation, path

The Fedora TeXLive packages do not correctly compile one of my documents. Others cannot reproduce this issue, so I'm testing if a separate TeXLive installation solves the problem.

The Fedora packages are installed to `/usr/bin/latex`; the separate TeXLive installation is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux`.

Now I need to set the PATH. Using `gedit ~/.profile`, I have added the following lines to the (previously blank) file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

This, as far as I can tell, is exactly what TeXLive told me to do.

However, `which latex` still returns `/usr/bin/latex`, not the expected `/usr/local` path.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why sudo in the edit of the .profile? Did you logout and back in, or source the .profile? Is .profile (as opposed to .bashrc) actually being sourced on login?

Comment: Using sudo was unnecessary, just a silly mistake on my part. Putting the PATH information in .bash_profile solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I sense there are a few possible fixes to address this, but the one that worked for me (and thus the only one that I've tried) was to include this PATH information not in .profile (as I had) but rather in .bash_profile. Otherwise, the existence of .bash_profile would basically override .profile and nothing would change. (I could have also pointed .bash_profile to use the information in .profile.)

Alternatively, it seems that I could remove .bash_profile (and perhaps a few other .bash* files), but I opted not to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

For many years I have handled my personal installations of TexLive with `~/.bashrc` (and friends).

At the end of my `~/.bashrc` I have:

```bsh
# User specific aliases and functions
if [ -f ${HOME}/.bashrc.${USER} ]; then
    . ${HOME}/.bashrc.${USER}
fi
```

and in my `~/.bashrc.rick` I have (in addition to lots of other stuff):

```bsh
export PATH=/home/rick/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}
export MANPATH=/home/rick/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:${MANPATH}
export INFOPATH=/home/rick/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info:${INFOPATH}
```

Every year I update the TexLive installation and the exported paths.  It has worked for me very well.